# Flex 3 columns, one smaller than the rest

Tags: css

I would like to evenly space around using flex on 3 columns but the last column is much smaller than the first 2, so I end up with dead space.

How do I take up the dead space to the right of the last column?

please see pic
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5YuR.jpg)

Here is the code I'm working with now:

```
#side {
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
}
#side > div {
  text-align:justify;
  padding:1.5rem;
  width:33.33%;
}

<div id="side">
  <div>long content</div>
  <div>long content</div>
  <div>short</div>
</div>
```

All 3 columns are equal (33.33%). The last column is much smaller than the first 2 so I would like to reclaim the dead space from the last element. How to do that with flex though?

Comment: that is hard to debug without seeing any code. please can you share some code, so we can run it? for example on codepen.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll get it now for you. Thanks

Comment: You forgot the HTML, I will need to copy and paste it somewhere, so I can run it.

Comment: There you go. Thanks again

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/s9fhx2Lw/1/ If you can, try to reproduce it in this jsfiddle, click ctrl+s for saving and then share the URL.

Comment: Okay, your fiddle is doing what I want to change. I must not be explaining the issue well enough. In your fiddle, look at the last box on the right. The content within it is smaller than the first 2 elements. How do I make the smaller element shrink to its content, then have the first 2 elements take up or reclaim that space from the last element?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4mt20koh/ like so?

Comment: You're very welcome, I added a comment. But I ain't a sir. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `flex: 1` in your CSS, which is a shorthand for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and some more.
`flex: 1` will take up all of the space available. If you would have two columns, column A with `flex: 1` and column B with `flex: 2`, that would mean that column B would take twice as much space as column B.

I can recommend this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

And here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/4mt20koh

Comment: Thank you Mähnenwolf and also for the explanation. This is very cool stuff for sure. I also noticed that you used `fit-content` on the flex items. I'll have to read more about this, I'm just getting my feet wet with flex. Thanks again!